# Computing the projection vector $\underline{p}$ given two vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Basically i'm given this:

$b = \begin{smallmatrix} -2\\4\\3 \end{smallmatrix}$ and $a = \begin{smallmatrix} 1\\3\\0 \end{smallmatrix}$

I need to project vector $b$ onto the line $a$.

It's also written that the projection error $e = b-p$, and i also need to check if is orthogonal to $a$.

So i started by computing the component $\frac{<a,b>}{|a|}$.

$\frac{-2+12}{\sqrt{4+16+9}}=\frac{10}{\sqrt{10}}$

Then i computed the projection:
$\frac{<a,b>}{|a|^2}a=\frac{12}{29}\begin{smallmatrix} 1\\3\\0 \end{smallmatrix}=\begin{smallmatrix} \frac{12}{29}\\\frac{36}{29}\\0 \end{smallmatrix}$

What do i need to do now?

Comment: I think $$\frac{<a.b>}{|a|}=\frac{-2+12}{\sqrt{1+9}}=\sqrt{10}$$

Answer (score 1):

Calculate $e=b-p$ and check, if $e*a=0$, where "*" denotes the scalar product.

Answer (score 1):

$$\overrightarrow{p}=\frac{<a.b>}{|a|}\frac{a}{|a|}=\frac{(-2+12)}{\sqrt{10}}\frac{(i+3j)}{\sqrt{10}}=(i+3j)$$